# How to ignore log file from sql server bak file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a 4GB bak file that I am trying to restore. In the Restore window in SQL Server Enterprise Edition I can see the bak is composed of two files: a row data type of file and a log data type of file.

Because SQL Server is asking for 50GB free space and given that I do not have that much space in my hard drive, is it possible to instruct SQL Server to only restore the row data file and ignore the log file?

Answer (score 3):

In short: no, it isn't.

Content of the log file is needed for the initial recovery. Without the log the transactional consistency cannot be guaranteed, because the updates are written first to log and only afterwards to a data file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the log then you can shrink it before you create the backup.

[Shrinking the Transaction Log](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178037%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)